# Image Changer in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to get my app to do a basic background change from 3 screens.  Here is my .h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class BIDYellowViewController;
@class BIDBlueViewController;
@class BIDGreenViewController;

@interface BIDSwitchViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) BIDYellowViewController *yellowViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) BIDBlueViewController *blueViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) BIDGreenViewController *greenViewController;

- (IBAction)switchViews:(id)sender;


@end
```

and here is my method in the .m file that when the IBAction button is pressed, the superview will go from one screen to the next and continue in the loop of rotating them.

```
- (IBAction)switchViews:(id)sender {
//animations
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
//loads yellow
    if (self.yellowViewController.view.superview == nil) {
        if (self.yellowViewController == nil) {
            self.yellowViewController = [[BIDYellowViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YellowView" bundle:nil];
        }
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
//removes blue
        [self.blueViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.yellowViewController.view atIndex:0];
//loads green
    } else if(self.greenViewController.view.superview == nil){
        if (self.greenViewController == nil) {
            self.greenViewController = [[BIDGreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GreenView" bundle:nil];
        }
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
//removes yellow
        [self.yellowViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.greenViewController.view atIndex:0];

//loads blue
    } else if(self.blueViewController.view.superview == nil){
        if (self.blueViewController == nil) {
            self.blueViewController = [[BIDBlueViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlueView" bundle:nil];
        }
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
//removes green
        [self.greenViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.blueViewController.view atIndex:0];
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

the problem I'm having is that on the first loop, it repeats green screen twice and then continues on and works properly.  Am I missing something or should I be using a switch: case statement( and if so how would I do that)?

Comment: If you have viewControllers then why you are using addSubView?.Or simple use UIView no need to use three viewControllers

Comment: you means you want to repeat it?Or stop repeating it

Comment: I need it to repeat. When the button is pressed it rotates to 'yellow'; press it again and it rotates to green; press it again and it rotates to blue; press again it rotates to yellow,....and so on and so on....I'm quite new to iOS/Xcode and am not sure where to plug in your suggestions? I need to have it set to that each color has a .h and .m file which I've already created.  Does some of your suggestions go in those files?  Any more detailed help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes that is repeating code I have given you check my answer

Comment: If you didn't understand where to put the code , then keep your code as it is and use count and switch as I have used in the switchViews method

Answer (score 0):

If want to repeat it continuously then use a global count variable as

```
static int count=0;
```

and use code as:

```
- (IBAction)switchViews:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];

    switch (count) {
        case 0:

            [greenView removeFromSuperview];
            [blueView removeFromSuperview];

            [self.view addSubview:yellowView];
            break;
        case 1:

            [yellowView removeFromSuperview];
            [greenView removeFromSuperview];

            [self.view addSubview:blueView];

            break;
        case 2:

            [blueView removeFromSuperview];
            [yellowView removeFromSuperview];

            [self.view addSubview:greenView];

            break;

    }

    count++;

    if (count==3) {
        count=0;
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

you can also use three xib's with single ViewController, just need to change the class of your xib to ViewController's class you want to use like this---

```
BIDViewController *yellowViewController;
BIDViewController *blueViewController;
BIDViewController *greenViewController;


self.yellowViewController = [[BIDViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YellowView" bundle:nil];
self.greenViewController = [[BIDViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GreenView" bundle:nil];
self.blueViewController = [[BIDViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlueView" bundle:nil];
```